# python selenium webscrape

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Hello i am trying to webscrape a web page using pyhton and selenium. The information i am trying to get from the page is match information / score board. for example the current set, the players name, the points each player has. i keep getting a TimeoutException. can someone show me how i can retrieve this information below is a link to an example of the page.

https://www.bovada.lv/sports/tennis/itf-men/chile-singles/a-tabilo-i-monzon-201811211325

below is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()  
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 50)
small_wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 50)


driver.execute_script('window.open("https://www.bovada.lv/sports/tennis/itf-men/chile-singles/a-tabilo-i-monzon-201811211325","_self")')

#//*[@id="tracker__header"]
dat = []
try:
    dat.append([wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tracker__header"]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]'))).text])
except TimeoutException:
    print('error')

driver.quit()
```

below is the information i want to get from the website
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to switch to iframe to get value:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('iframe[id^="iframe-tracker-"]'))
try:
    dat.append(wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tracker__header"]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]'))).text)
except TimeoutException:
    print('error')
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is most likely switch to frames. You can do that by inspecting element and find the iframe section. Right click on is and copy the x-path.

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath('YOUR IFRAME XPATH)
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

Now you can run your code just fine, hopefully.